# Multiple processes appending to file result in overwriting

Tags: powershell, append, registry, mutex, overwrite

I have a simple powershell command that appends a variable (string) into a .log file:

```
powershell.exe -command " \"%V\" | out-file "C:\file.log" -append "
```

This is stored inside the registry, and so %V equals to a directory path.

Whenever I execute this command, the directory path gets appended to the log file.
The problems start happening when I call 15 instances of this command - the results are awful (for example, I'll only see 3 out of 15 entries in my log file). I believe this is called [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition), where multiple instances are trying to access the file at the same time, resulting in overwriting.

I tried to solve this problem by using mutex, so that only one instance will actually be appending the path to the log file at a time:

```
powershell.exe -command " $mtx = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, \"RCWM\");
$mtx.WaitOne();
\"%V\" | out-file "C:\file.log" -append;
$mtx.ReleaseMutex() "
```

This works, but it's very slow.

Is there anything else I can do to speed this process up, while only allowing one instance to output to the file at a time?

Comment: Show how you’re populating %V

Comment: %V is just a variable inside windows registry which holds the folder path.For all purposes of my question, %V is just a string.

Comment: The problem is not in overwriting %V, since I call many powershell instances and in each of them %V holds the right information.

Comment: Your issue makes no sense. That's why I asked. Good luck.

Comment: It's simply a matter of multiple processes trying to access the file at the same time (race condition).

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: I didn't ... I just explained the issue I'm trying to avoid in more detail.